# Discussion about new tags we may need to add to the site or otherwise make on-topic

Tags: discussion, site-topic, tags, promotion, help-center

### Revisiting Tags and Topics to Remain Relevant & Encourage More High-Quality Questions

Recently, [this post](https://pm.stackexchange.com/q/34988/4271) caught my eye bcause at first glance I didn't think it was a PM question. After looking more carefully at it, and at the type of answers and comments it attracted, it seemed like it was not only on topic, but possibly an area we can mine for more engagement with the community.

Basically, I wanted to open the floor to see if we should be *proactively* adding tags for things like `Root Cause Analysis (RCA)`, `Causal Maps`, or other things that are part of the PM accountability related to uncovering or addressing organizational dysfunction related to project management without sliding into definitively off-topic areas like:

- Anything that really belongs on The Workplace.
- Interpersonal conflict management.
- Organizational change management.

There's probably a lot of other things that we haven't focused on over the years. As others have pointed out, a lot of the older questions were about methodologies that have fallen out of favor, or about Scrum and agile practices that are no longer "new and shiny."

What topics should we actively be *promoting* on the site, rather than just assuming people will know what's on-topic and what isn't? I'd like to come up with at least 3-5 new tags, and maybe add some stuff to the on-topic portion of our help center.

Thoughts? Ideas? Rotten tomatoes?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for bringing this up, Todd!

Needless to say (as the OP for the mentioned question), I strongly agree with your suggestion.

I've observed that for a while pm.se is being heavily used towards MS Project questions and I have the impression that agile-related questions are (still) diluted across other SE sites.

With that in mind, I agree with your suggestions on bringing up tags related to techniques that could be helpful for project managers and team leads in general.

The challenge on suggesting them is that, like in the original question, in the best case scenario the technique is "known" but the actual name of it is not... and in worst case scenario, even the technique isn't known. So, even if we create the tag, the bulk of work would be to somehow "socialise" each tag and how it could help managers or leaders.

From the top of my head what occurs me is to have a meta post related to each new tag proposed, explaining how it can benefit the community.